# Javascript library load order in IntelliJ causing incorrect function signatures

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellij-idea, code-completion

I'm working on a javascript web project that includes no extra libraries or frameworks but jQuery.

I created a project as "Static Web".

In `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries` i added and enabled jquery, and I can confirm it works.

"HTML" is also enabled.

However, inside my code, on `$('...').insertBefore(...)` it uses the definition from the "HTML" module "DOMCore.js" instead of jQuery.js. Because of this, its giving incorrect warnings about incorrect function arguments.

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to consider the jQuery library before the HTML library? If not, why is IntelliJ not remembering the type of a jQuery object when it is declared?

Just for clarity sake, this isn't on just `.insertBefore()`. It also happens on other functions like `.find()` (which uses `EcmaScript6.js>Array.prototype.find`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Elena Pogorelova* of IntelliJ helped me out with this one. Answer is to use jquery Typescript community stubs for type resolving instead (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000555830/comments/115000461584). Though that currently brings up other issues, they are working on it.